# XML Schema same attributes names but different attribute values?

Tags: xsd

I have got service with a method with request of a following format:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"         xmlns:com="http://com.org.srv">
 <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
   <com:methodName>
     <com:someParam>value</com:someParam>
     <com:param name="firstPoint">
        <com:param name="code">value</com:param>
     </com:param>
     <com:param name="firstPointDesc">
        <com:param name="pName">value</com:param>
        <com:param name="pLo">value</com:param>
     </com:param>
     <com:param name="endPoint">
        <com:param name="code">value</com:param>
     </com:param>
     <com:param name="endPointDesc">
        <com:param name="pName">value</com:param>
        <com:param name="pLo">value</com:param>
     </com:param>
     <com:param name="bunch">
        <com:param name="temperature">val</com:param>
        <com:param name="humidity">val</com:param>
        <com:param name="pressure">val</com:param>
     </com:param>
  </com:methodName>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This information was provided as-is and i need to describe it in xsd file in eclipse. 
I have tried:

```
<element name="methodNameRequest">
    <complexType>
        <sequence maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
            <element name="someParam" type="string" maxOccurs="1"
                minOccurs="1">
            </element>
            <element name="deviceId" type="string"></element>
            <element name="param" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="param" maxOccurs="1"
                            minOccurs="1">
                            <complexType>
                                <simpleContent>
                                    <extension base="string">
                                        <attribute name="name"
                                            type="string" default="code" />
                                    </extension>
                                </simpleContent>
                            </complexType>
                        </element>
                    </sequence>
                    <attribute name="name" type="string"
                        default="firstPoint" />
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="params" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="param" maxOccurs="1"
                            minOccurs="1">
                            <complexType>
                                <simpleContent>
                                    <extension base="string">
                                        <attribute name="name"
                                            type="string" default="pName" />
                                    </extension>
                                </simpleContent>
                            </complexType>
                        </element>
                        <element name="param" maxOccurs="1"
                            minOccurs="1">
                            <complexType>
                                <simpleContent>
                                    <extension base="string">
                                        <attribute name="name"
                                            type="string" default="pLo" />
                                    </extension>
                                </simpleContent>
                            </complexType>
                        </element>
                    </sequence>
                    <attribute name="name" type="string"
                        default="firstPointDesc" />
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="params" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="param" maxOccurs="1"
                            minOccurs="1">
                            <complexType>
                                <simpleContent>
                                    <extension base="string">
                                        <attribute name="name"
                                            type="string" default="code" />
                                    </extension>
                                </simpleContent>
                            </complexType>
                        </element>
                    </sequence>
                    <attribute name="name" type="string"
                        default="endPoint" />
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="params" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="param" maxOccurs="1"
                            minOccurs="1">
                            <complexType>
                                <simpleContent>
                                    <extension base="string">
                                        <attribute name="name"
                                            type="string" default="pName" />
                                    </extension>
                                </simpleContent>
                            </complexType>
                        </element>
                        <element name="param" maxOccurs="1"
                            minOccurs="1">
                            <complexType>
                                <simpleContent>
                                    <extension base="string">
                                        <attribute name="name"
                                            type="string" default="pLo" />
                                    </extension>
                                </simpleContent>
                            </complexType>
                        </element>
                    </sequence>
                    <attribute name="name" type="string"
                        default="endPointDesc" />
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="param" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="param" maxOccurs="1"
                            minOccurs="1">
                            <complexType>
                                <simpleContent>
                                    <extension base="string">
                                        <attribute name="name"
                                            type="string" default="temperature" />
                                    </extension>
                                </simpleContent>
                            </complexType>
                        </element>
                        <element name="param" maxOccurs="1"
                            minOccurs="1">
                            <complexType>
                                <simpleContent>
                                    <extension base="string">
                                        <attribute name="name"
                                            type="string" default="humidity" />
                                    </extension>
                                </simpleContent>
                            </complexType>
                        </element>
                        <element name="param" maxOccurs="1"
                            minOccurs="1">
                            <complexType>
                                <simpleContent>
                                    <extension base="string">
                                        <attribute name="name"
                                            type="string" default="pressure" />
                                    </extension>
                                </simpleContent>
                            </complexType>
                        </element>
                    </sequence>
                    <attribute name="name" type="string"
                        default="bunch" />
                </complexType>
            </element>
 ....
```

but with no success: `Multiple elements with name 'param', with different types, appear in the model group.` reported by eclipse.

Can anybody provide a valid example of `xsd` description for this or similar structure?
I am not in common with wsdl schemas and services at all.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The designers of the XML vocabulary appear to have been working to make the XML unvalidatable using normal XML tools; they may have succeeded.  To foil their nefarious plan, your best bet is probably either to map their XML into isomorphic but more easily validatable XML (make those attribute values be element names, for example), or else look into XSD 1.1 assertions, and work on your XPath 2.0 skills.